# Angular 5 convert Observable<obj> to obj

Tags: angular, angular5, observable

I'm implementing `resolve` method:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Obj> | Obj {
        return this.service.get(route.params['guid'])
            .map((response: Json) => {
                return this.service.list(response.data.id).map((response: Json) => {
                    return <Obj>response.data;
                });
        });
```

But I have error `Can't convert to Observable<Observable<Obj>>`.

How can I resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make this return an `Obj` because it's async. Therefore, it must be unwrapped. You can make it an `Observable<Obj>` by using `mergeMap`:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Obj> {
        return this.service.get(route.params['guid'])
            .mergeMap((response: Json) => {
                return this.service.list(response.data.id).map((response: Json) => {
                    return response.data;
                });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

The result inside a `map` is already an Observable. Try this :

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Obj> | Obj {
        return this.service.get(route.params['guid'])
            .mergeMap((response: Json) => {
                return this.service.list(response.data.id).map((response: Json) => {
                    return response.data;
                });
        });
```

**EDIT**: @Rafael is right, you must also use `mergeMap` (of flapMap if you are using a rxjs version < 6), I edited my post.